# Canva Editor Flutter Clone

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a template editor like the one in Canva using Flutter. I will get the template as a JSON from BE and the requirement is to render it in Flutter, and then allow manipulations like scaling, rotation, translation, etc. and then send the updated JSON to the BE. Currently what I have done is rendered the different objects in the template using Stack. Currently I am having trouble with Texts. Currently I am rendering everything in a container with fixed height and width. So in the case of texts, the requirement is to increase the size of the text on scaling the container, and also if we type in more text and if it overflows the container, the height or width of the container should automatically increase. Also using Translate.scale is not an option because it won't return the correct dx and dy offset after scaling. Any pointers on this would be helpful.

Thank You.